# Having trouble with attribute != selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The question is simple, the answer maybe not.

I'm trying to apply several styles to all input elements without an specific id. I use this selector in my CSS stylesheet: `input[id!='move']` but unfortunately it's not working either in IE10 or in Chrome.

The curious thing is that this block: `input:not(#move)` works perfectly in both.
I'm lost because the first block of code is supposed to work as far as I understand how these kind of selectors work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't exclude an attribute by using [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) alone - using `!` to exclude an attribute value in CSS is invalid. If you *need* to exclude an ID you will have to include the [`:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation) pseudo-class.

Answer (score 8):

That is a non-standard attribute selector [invented by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector). It's not part of the [Selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors), so it won't work anywhere outside of jQuery (this includes things like `document.querySelectorAll()`).

Strictly speaking, the direct equivalent of jQuery's `input[id!='move']` in standard selector syntax is `input:not([id='move'])`, with an attribute selector. But since you're looking to match elements without a specific ID, `input:not(#move)` is fine.